# Managing the dialog form in C#

Tags: c#, forms, dialog

On click of a button I have this code with is should show a dialog on top of the current form and display text, wait for one second, change the text and then finally close it:

```
Form p = new Form();
p.ShowDialog();

p.Text = "Start.";
Thread.Sleep(1000);

p.Text = "Counting.";
Thread.Sleep(1000);

p.Text = "End.";
Thread.Sleep(1000);

p.Close();
```

However once it executes `p.ShowDialog();` it stops the code until the form p is closed and it doesn't work as I intended it to. Can I get some guidance on this? Not necessarily the solution, but at least maybe some keywords I could google on?

**UPDATE:** due to the difficulties I am facing trying to access business logic, which is irrelevant to the problem, I am delaying providing the working example. Stay tuned and sorry :)

**SOLUTION:** what I did is in fact used `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()`. Since i was impossible to access form from business logic, BackgroundWorker came in handy and was being used between them. I cannot share any code or the layout of the project structure, but in conclusion, the accepted answer's main statement was the key to the solution :)

Comment: You really should do the code from within the form and in a separate thread using invoke

Comment: On a separate note, don't use Dialog Boxes. They are just evil. :) See if you can display the same message in some vacant area of your parent form. That way its less irritating to user and code is easy to write too!

Comment: Could you kindly provide some feedback on my answer? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, sorry, I wasn't working during the weekend :)

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius Follow up:  Don't forget to mark as *correct* the answer that helped you with your problem

Comment: This is the first time I really cannot find a spare second at work to write it and at home I have no access to the working code. Please be patient, I am sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the point of ShowDialog().  It creates a modal form and does not return control to the calling function until you are done.  If it doesn't need to be modal, then use .Show().  If it does need to be modal, then put code in the Form Load method to update the text as needed.

Comment: You won't be able to just put this code in the modal form, or run this code if it's not modal, as it would involve sleeping in the UI thread.  IN either case you'll need to switch to using a `Timer`, or similar.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx

taken from the link above:

`When this method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed.`

if you want to form to display whatever it is you want to display you should write the code inside the the form itself, do that in an eventhandler of the form show event.

Answer (score 2):

As you have found, `ShowDialog` is a blocking method that does not return until the dialog is closed.  Your code to change the text and handle the delay needs to be within the dialogue itself.

However, it's worth noting the next problem that you'll find: if you call `Thread.Sleep(1000)` from the UI thread, your application will become unresponsive for 1 second at a time.  This is probably not what you're aiming for!  I'd suggest you look into the `Timer` or `BackgroundWorker` classes to handle this more smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
    delegate void CloseFormCallback();

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        new Thread(DoMagic).Start();
    }

    public void DoMagic()
    {
        this.SetText("Start.");

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        this.SetText("Counting.");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        this.SetText("End");

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        this.CloseForm();
    }

    private void CloseForm()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            CloseFormCallback c = new CloseFormCallback(CloseForm);
            this.Invoke(c);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        if (this.label1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.label1.Text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not going to work for me, because depending on the data I will need to make calls from the parent form and do that dynamically. So I am unable to put that in a thread which is in Form2. I am pretty sure there is a workaround, but it seems that there is no need for threading for what I am trying to achieve, because simple show instead of showdialog seems to have fixed the issue. I will update with more information tomorrow. Thanks for the effort trying to help me :)

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius I can modify it to get dynamic messages from the parent Form. However, I don't see how you will be able to show a form and close it without using another thread. Anyone, if you've already designed a solution, share it with us =)